# MySQL access denied error but everything is correct!

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1045

Here's my code

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'sam_sam';
$password = '[censored]';
$name = 'sam_ballpointradio';
mysql_connect($host, $db_username, $db_password)
or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

and the error message is

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'sam'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/sam/public_html/ballpointradio/db_config.php  on line 6
>   Access denied for user 'sam'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I know all the information is correct, but it's a weird error because it says I'm NOT using a password, but I am...

Comment: No, you aren't using a password. The variable name is misspelled.

Comment: Wow...I am an idiot....

..thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Variable naming problem ?

```
mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)
```